# How to read BLOB with SharkORM

Tags: ios, sqlite, dbaccess

I would like to read a BLOB field from an SQLite database with SharkORM but I don't know how to properly do it. Here is the model I use:

```
class Entries: SRKObject {
@objc dynamic var _id = 0
@objc dynamic var meaning = ""
@objc dynamic var path: NSData? = nil
```

}

and the query is the following one:

```
let results: SRKResultSet = Entries.query().limit(1).fetch()
    print(results)
```

I know that the BLOB are not null in the database because I can see some data with an SQLite database viewer and the Android app using the same DB can read the BLOB. But with my implementation in iOS, the result of the above code always returns  for the BLOB.

Does anyone know how to read BLOB with SharkORM?

Thank you!